base64 encoded image partially displayed upon decoding in UTF-8 (AI-related question)
I am testing out an AI-feedback system that analyzes batches of documents (mainly PDF type files). It works by summarizing each page and then summarizing all of the summaries into one cohesive summary.
This is my code that handles the summaries. I have checked Gemini 1.5 Flash API documentation, and there were some limitations when it comes to the length or resolution in which an image (as base64 string) is passed into Gemini/Vertex. AI. I am working with image files of around 2MB.
# Function to generate image summaries using Gemini API
def generate_image_summary(image_path):
    global summaryllm

    try:
        # Read image with PIL first to ensure it's valid
        with Image.open(image_path) as img:
            # Convert to RGB if necessary
            if img.mode not in ('RGB', 'RGBA'):
                img = img.convert('RGB')
            
            # Save to bytes with controlled settings
            buffer = io.BytesIO()
            img.save(
                buffer, 
                format="PNG",
                optimize=True,
            )
            # Get binary data
            binary_data = buffer.getvalue()
            #buffer.seek(0)
            #image_bytes = buffer.read()

        # Encode to base64 with proper padding
        base64_image = base64.b64encode(binary_data).decode('utf-8')
        
        # Ensure proper MIME type in data URL
        image_url = f"data:image/png;base64,{base64_image}"
        print("The image URL is:", image_url)
        
        # Validate the base64 string
        try:
            # Test decode to verify the base64 string is valid
            # base64.b64decode(base64_image)
            test_decode = base64.b64decode(base64_image)
            # Verify the decoded data matches the original
            if test_decode != binary_data:
                raise ValueError("Base64 encoding/decoding verification failed")
        except Exception as e:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid base64 encoding: {str(e)}")

        summary = summaryllm.invoke(
            [
                HumanMessage(
                    content=[
                        {"type": "text", "text": summary_prompt},
                        {"type": "image_url", "image_url": image_url},
                    ]
                )
            ]
        )
        return summary.content
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f"Error processing image {image_path}: {str(e)}")
        return None
    
    # Read the image from the file and convert it to Base64
    #with open(image_path, "rb") as img_file:
        #buffer = img_file.read()
        #base64_image = base64.b64encode(buffer).decode("utf-8")

    #image_url = f"data:image/png;base64,{base64_image}"
    #print("The image URL is:", image_url)

    #summary = summaryllm.invoke(
       # [
            #HumanMessage(
                #content=[
                    #{"type": "text", "text": summary_prompt},
                    #{"type": "image_url", "image_url": image_url},
                #]
            #)
        #]
    #)
    #return summary.content

# Function to generate an overall summary of image summaries
def generate_overall_summary(image_summaries):
    global summaryllm

    # Combine all image summaries into a single text
    combined_summaries = "\n\n".join([doc.page_content for doc in image_summaries])

    message = HumanMessage(
        content=[
            {"type": "text", "text": overallsummary_prompt},
            {"type": "text", "text": f"{combined_summaries}"}
        ]
    )

    # Generate the summary using the LLM
    overall_summary = summaryllm.invoke([message])
    
    return overall_summary.content

I initially used fitz to do the processing of the images, but after a few failed attempts to obtain cropped image file, I switched over to pdf2image to do the heavy lifting in terms of page to image extraction/processing. The issue I suspect is happening, is erroneous conversion of the image file to base64, which could be due to the image resolution or the way I handle base64 conversions.
My base64 conversion process starts with opening the file using io or the BytesIO method. This is shown in this code snippet:
# Function to save a PDF page as an image
def save_pdf_page_as_image(pdf_path, output_folder, page_index, image_hashes, poppler_path):
    try:
        images = convert_from_path(pdf_path, first_page=page_index + 1, last_page=page_index + 1, poppler_path=poppler_path, fmt="PNG", dpi=300)
        if not images:
            raise ValueError("No images generated from PDF.")
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f"Error processing PDF page: {e}")
        return None

    image = images[0]  # Get the single page we are processing

    # Ensure image is in RGB mode
    if image.mode != 'RGB':
        image = image.convert('RGB')

    # Convert image to bytes for hashing
    image_bytes_io = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(image_bytes_io, 
        format="PNG",
        optimize=True
        )
    
    image_bytes = image_bytes_io.getvalue()
    # Compute image hash for uniqueness
    image_hash = hashlib.md5(image_bytes).hexdigest()

    if image_hash not in image_hashes:
        # Save the image locally
        image_name = f"{os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pdf_path))[0]}_page{page_index + 1}_image.png"
        image_path = os.path.join(output_folder, image_name)
        #image.save(image_path)

        # Save the image to disk with the same settings
        with open(image_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(image_bytes)

        #image.save(
            #image_path,
            #format="PNG",
            #optimize=True,
            #quality=95
        #)

        # Add hash to the list to avoid duplicates
        image_hashes.append(image_hash)
        # Return the image path (no Base64 generation here)
        return image_path
    return None

For a larger context/overview of the main function, it is shown here. I allowed the user to upload their file, which would be saved and opened temporarily for processing. After the summaries are completed, the file is closed and deleted. The rest of the code focuses on summarizing the pages and then summarizing the summaries to obtain a thorough, yet brief overview of the document
@st.cache_resource(show_spinner=False)
def process_and_embed_assignments(assignment_batches):
    global embeddings

    for pdfs in assignment_batches:
        # Initialize empty lists for the current function's scope.
        image_paths = []
        image_hashes = []
        image_summaries = []

        temp_pdf_path = f"./{pdfs.name}"
        with open(temp_pdf_path, mode='wb') as w:
            w.write(pdfs.getvalue())

        #Extract images from the PDF
        pdf_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(temp_pdf_path))[0]

        # Define the folder to save images
        output_folder = f"Images//{pdf_name}"
        os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

        # Iterate over each page and save it as an image using pdf2image
        pdf_info = convert_from_path(temp_pdf_path, poppler_path=popular_path)
        total_pages = len(pdf_info)
        for page_index in range(total_pages):
            image_path = save_pdf_page_as_image(temp_pdf_path, output_folder, page_index, image_hashes, popular_path)
            if image_path:
                image_paths.append(image_path)

        # remove temporary pdf
        os.remove(f"./{pdfs.name}")

        # Generate summaries for the extracted images
        # for image_path in image_paths:
        for page_index, images in enumerate(image_paths):
            image_name = f"{pdf_name}_page_{page_index + 1}.png"
            if os.path.exists(image_path) and os.path.getsize(image_path) > 0:
                # Process image
                summary = generate_image_summary(image_path)
            else:
                st.error(f"Invalid or empty image file: {image_path}")
                continue
            summary = generate_image_summary(images)
            document = Document(
                page_content=summary,
                metadata={"name": image_name}
            )
            image_summaries.append(document)
            time.sleep(5)  # Adjust the sleep time as needed

        # Generate a summary of the summaries for the entire PDF
        overall_summary_content = generate_overall_summary(image_summaries)
        overall_summary_document = Document(
            page_content=overall_summary_content,
            metadata={"name": f"{pdf_name}_overall_summary"}  # Metadata for the overall summary
        )
        # Add the overall summary to the image_summaries list
        image_summaries.append(overall_summary_document)

The issue comes when I am debugging my code. The summaries and image extraction/processing does not raise any exceptions/errors, however, when I was calling my vector database for retrieval, I noticed some documents had descriptions where Gemini found "no charts or images provided, and only a text description was given". I dug a bit deeper into my base64 strings and found out that they were very different in terms of the way it displays. I have shown two examples below.
Notice how the entire page does not render? Only a tiny portion of the title loads as shown
Compare that to this base64 decoded string, which renders/displays the entire page (Slighlty censored for minor confidentiality
I am not sure how to proceed. I reran my code a few times to see if encoding the string via bytes value, pixmap, or local image path will resolve the issue, but none has sufficed.
P.S. I did use Claude, ChatGPT and perplexity to suggest ideas on how to modify my code, so take whatever code I have given as a grain of salt. The feedback system was made to do all the conversion and extractions locally, hence the hard-coded nature of my current system as of today.

About I am testing out an AI-feedback system that analyzes batches of documents (mainly PDF type files)., in your situation, you are required to convert PDF to image? For example, how about directly using PDF? Ref But, I cannot understand your actual expected result. So, if I misunderstood your question and this was not useful, I apologize.

I’d like to clarify that in my current situation, I am required to work with multi modal data (image and text) within my PDF files, which emulates the various subjects that this system should work with in the real world. The reference was not that useful, but it is a good starting point.

I did find a link that shows some steps on how to parse PDF files into Gemini directly link
